# When to use “qui” and when to use “lequel” or “laquelle”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I am not sure when to use *qui* and when to use *lequel* ou *laquelle*. I would like to have a precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://frenchcrazy.com/2013/12/french-relative-pronouns-dont-qui-que-lequel-ou.html/ :

### Qui

> *Qui* can refer to people or things and is used as the subject of a dependent clause. Because *qui* becomes the subject of the sentence it is always followed by a conjugated verb and must agree in number with the antecedent it is referring to.
>
> « On critique les films qui montrent trop de nudité. » →
> "People criticize films that display too much nudity."

### Lequel/Laquelle

> The relative pronoun *lequel* (and all of its forms) replace a preposition (other than de) and a thing/object in a relative clause. Make sure that the pronoun agrees in both number and gender to whatever it is describing.
>
> « Une langue est un prisme à travers lequel ses usagers sont condamnés à voir le monde. » →
> "A language is a prism across which its users are condemned to see the world."

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer that is not academic but helped me a lot in learning to use *lequel* as an English speaker.

Effectively, just use *lequel* whenever you want to replace things like:

- dans (j'ai une boîte dans laquelle je mets tous mes trucs)
- avec (elle est la fille avec laquelle j'ai parlé hier)
- sur (c'est la table sur laquelle il y a un gateâu)
- à traves (c'est la vitrine à traves de laquelle on peut voir le truc)
  I can't think of any more prepositions but yeah, you get the idea...

Whereas for *qui,* think of VERBS

- le mec qui a largué sa copine (qui + larguer)
- le prof qui est nul (qui + être)
- le so on so forth

Hope this helps. I am not native speaker so might not be 100 percent correct.